# How to write the interval?

Tags: normal-distribution

[image: table 1]
[image: table 2]
When I was given table 1 and wanted to transform it into the format in table 2 so that I can calculate the probability, how do I write? 
In reference to table 1, for example, the 155-159 and 160-164 class, should I write: 
155 ≤ X ≤159 and 160 ≤ X ≤164
(But this way it is not continuous and the probabilities will not add up to 1)
or
155 ≤ X < 160 and 160 ≤X < 165 
(But the answers don’t seem to be correct) 
or
154 < X ≤ 159 and 159 < X ≤ 164 
?

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the question you are asked to do in the first place; here it suffices to just compute a test statistic using the frequency data and the null hypothesis. Presumably you can interpret each of the intervals as their midpoint (so for example you could treat the 170-174 interval as being 64 172s).

Comment: That said, when comparing integer-valued data with a continuous approximation, we commonly replace each integer $x$ with the interval $(x-0.5,x+0.5)$. This is sometimes called the continuity correction. This will address your concern about covering the whole line.

Comment: @Ian I get it know. Thank u very much